# Regex for DateTimeOffset validation in url?

Tags: c#, regex, datetimeoffset

How to validate the date and time in the url that is the correct DateTimeOffset format?

DateTimeOffset format (basically starts with 4 digits of year and end with uppercase Z):

- yyyy-mm-dd**Z**
- yyyy-mm-dd**T**hh:mm:ss**Z**
- yyyy-mm-dd**T**hh:mm:ss.fffff**Z**

Valid DateTimeOffset in the url:

- aaa.com/activityDateTime eq **2022-05-12Z**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime eq **2022-05-12T12:00:00Z**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime%20eq%20**2022-05-12T12:00:00Z**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime+eq+**2022-05-12T12:00:00.123456Z**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime gt **2022-03-12Z** le **2022-05-12Z**

*Note: eq means equal, gt means greater than, le means less than*

Invalid DateTimeOffset in the url:

- aaa.com/activityDateTime eq **2022-05-12**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime eq **2022-05-12T12:00:00**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime%20eq%20**2022-05-12T12:00:00**
- aaa.com/activityDateTime+eq+**2022-05-12T12:00:00.123456**

I'm currently convert the url to string and use Regex to validate it, but not sure what's the proper way to handle the case where url contains "%20". Is there a way not to use Replace()? Also, any other suggestions to validate DateTimeOffset in the url?
Here's my current regex expression:

```
Regex checkDate = new Regex(@"^(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}Z)");
Regex checkDateTime = new Regex(@"^(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z)");
```

Comment: You can use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=net-6.0) to get rid of the %20

Comment: I'd take a step back and question why you're using Regex and why you're doing it on a URL string. It looks like you're using C#: why not parse the URL with the `Uri` class and try to parse the DateTimeOffset with the `DateTimeOffset` class? In fact, it looks like you're using `OData`: why not use [OdataUriParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/use-uri-parser)? OData [follows a standard](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/) for formatting DateTimeOffset: if possible you should use that rather than write your own regex.

Comment: Thank you @GuyVdN, I completely forgot that I can use it.

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior this is a very solid suggestion, I'm new to Odata and I will look into those!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regex to validate DateTimeOffset, you can use the following one:

```
^[A-Za-z\.\/]+( |%20|\+)(eq|gt)( |%20|\+)[\d\-]+(T[\d:]+(\.[\d]+)?Z|Z( [a-z]+ [\d\-]+Z)?)$
```

Explanation:

- `^`: start string
- `[A-Za-z\.\/]+`: any combination of alphabetic character, dots and slashes
- `( |%20|\+)`: single space or %20 or +
- `(eq|gt)`: eq or gt
- `( |%20|\+)`: single space or %20 or +
- `[\d\-]+`: any combination of digits and dashes (the date)

The last part `(T[\d:]+(\.[\d]+)?Z|Z( [a-z]+ [\d\-]+Z)?)` can match one between two different suffixes.

Suffix 1 `T[\d:]+(\.[\d]+)?Z`:

- `T`: T
- `[\d:]+`: any combination of digits and : (the time)
- `(\.[\d]+)?`: optional presence of single dot with a combination of digits (milliseconds?)
- `Z`: Z

Suffix 2 `Z( [a-z]+ [\d\-]+Z)?`:

- `Z`: Z
- `( [a-z]+ [\d\-]+Z)?`: optional presence of a space, followed by letters, a space, combination of digits and dashes (a date), a Z

The whole regex is wrapped up with:

- `$`: end of string

If instead you want to match only the DateTimeOffset, use only the following part of this regex:

```
[\d\-]+(T[\d:]+(\.[\d]+)?Z|Z( [a-z]+ [\d\-]+Z)?)$
```

Test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/fRgaFo/1).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into OData more but really appreciate your Regex suggestion!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! If this answer solves your problem, make sure to update your question as answered to save devs' time for other yet open problems. @S.P.